# Grey screen after Kubuntu wake-up from sleep

Tags: linux, kubuntu, wake-up

After my Kubuntu wakes up from sleep mode, the screen is grey and the only thing I can do is to turn power off. I can't even go to console using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. How to make wake-up work correctly? It works correctly on Win7 installed on the other partition. I'm using laptop.

Comment: Are you using a laptop or a desktop?

Comment: @criziot laptop

Comment: Please try to increase/decrease screen luminosity.

Comment: @criziot Luminosity is not the problem here. In fact whatever key I press, there is no change on the screen.

Comment: When my laptop wakes up from sleep the screen backlight stays off untill I press luminosity buttons and I have Ubuntu. That's why I've asked you to try it.

Comment: @criziot thanks for the idea. Actually my screen backlight is on and the whole screen is grey. Any other idea?

Comment: I will check the log files (record the time you wake up your laptop and then check the logs around that time) but I don't know of anything else that could help you.

Comment: @criziot I used `cat /var/log/* | grep hh:mm` in around the wake-up time but I found nothing. I will try once more.

Comment: @criziot see [here](http://pastebin.com/7ftVibXg) - logs from 21:17. I started sleep mode in around 21:17:04 and woke kubuntu up around 21:17:22. To get this I used the command from above.

Comment: Sorry, no clues from the logs.